# Converting a STRING to PGN in CAPL

Tags: vector, capl

I am preparing a simulation in CAPL for almost 200+ pgn which is in *.xls format.
1)Is there any way to convert the string to pgn datatype?
2) Other method to convert the 200+ PGNs to capl with prio would be really helful?

Comment: Please elaborate what format you want the output.